# Naming a workbook with a password

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out how to add a password to my workbook. The code does save it when I remove the password part ("sp17"), but I get a syntax error while its there. How would I correct this error?

```
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileLocation degreeArray(criteria) & " " & format(Date, "MMM-YY") & ".xlsx", 51, "sp17"
```

Comment: Your path/file string is incorrect (missing &).  The following is a sample:  

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:="<your path and file>", FileFormat:=52, Password:="password", WriteResPassword:="password", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

Comment: the problem ended up being with the actual word format. After I changed it to a capital F it worked just fine.

Comment: Are you saying the issue was with "format(Date..." and you corrected by making it "Format(Date...)?  I hope not, because that was 100% not the cause of the problem. Try typing any reserved word into VBA, using all lowercase, and you will see it is automatically converted to the proper Upper/Lower mixture.  Please note that you added the ampersand (&) to your code to specify the proper file location -- that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small change and now it works. The Format was written incorrectly. Thought about deleting my question but it was hard to find out how to do this so i'll leave it for any one who needs it. This was the right way to write it:

```
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileLocation & degreeArray(criteria) & " " & Format(Date, "MMM-YY") & ".xlsx", 51, Password:="sp17"
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as *the answer* after 48 hours (48 hour period required when answering your own question).

Comment: fwiw, I typically leave off the ` & ".xlsx"` portion and let the **xlFileFormat** determine the appropriate file extension to add; e.g `, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` or `, 51` .

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Jeeped!